# Setting generic type based on object's properties type

Tags: typescript

I defined an interface for an object which looks like that

```js
interface ICustomer {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  tags: string[];
}
```

and I have a generic interface for updating the object's properties:

```js
interface IUpdate<T> {
  changed:boolean;
  value: T; 
}
```

I want to define an object type of this shape:

```js
interface ICustomerUpdate {
  name: IUpdate<string>;
  age: IUpdate<number>;
  tags: IUpdate<string[]>;
}
```

How can I do it without explicitly define each property?
I have the beginning:

```js
type CustomerUpdate = Record<keyof ICustomer, IUpdate<???>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) are what you need to use for this:

```js
type IUpdateRecord<T extends {}> = {
    [K in keyof T]: IUpdate<T[K]>;
};
```

Here is the full answer based on your example code:

```js
interface ICustomer {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  tags: string[];
}

interface IUpdate<T> {
  changed:boolean;
  value: T; 
}

type IUpdateRecord<T extends {}> = {
    [K in keyof T]: IUpdate<T[K]>;
};

type ICustomerUpdate = IUpdateRecord<ICustomer>;
/*
result:

type ICustomerUpdate = {
  name: IUpdate<string>;
  age: IUpdate<number>;
  tags: IUpdate<string[]>;
}
*/
```